# How to extract certain words from a string based on the existence of other words?

Tags: python-3.x

So i have what appears to be a rather basic problem that probably has a simple solution but i probably need a function i am not aware of (new to programming). For this assignment i need to get a certain word/words relative to the position of some other "key" word. 
Ex of what i need to retrieve:
A valid person's information in a description will contain the following: 1. a string "name is" after which a single space and a name (first name and last name), separated by single space.
2. single space before and after that two digits representing the person's age after which we have single space and the word "years"
3. birthday date - before the date we should have the word "on" after that single space and then date in exact format dd-mm-yyyy (months will be digits and the date should be separated with "-" {dd-mm-yyyy})

This is given as the practice string:

```
Hello,everyone my name is Maria Mariova. I am 22 years old. was born on 22-06-1994.
```

I've been going at this for a few hours but no luck. Looked mainly into re but didn't seem to find what i need. the goal is to get the data i need in a variable so that i can pass it in wherever needed.

Comment: Well, regular expressions definitely seem like the way to go here. You are on the right track.

Comment: given you example input data, what should the method return?  Can you post example of what you expect?

Comment: `regex` - a bit hard at first but extremly powerful once you get used to it. A good helper is e.g. https://regex101.com/

Comment: @MrFuppes regex seems to be the way to go indeed. When i first saw it i though that would be too complicated for this course since it's a fundamental one but a friend of mine explained to me what RegEx actually was and is helping me out now. thanks a lot for the help, i should be able to handle it from here.